# In Koa.js how to upload a CSV file and read its content and import it into MongoDB collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, koa, koa2

In Koa.js how can we upload a CSV file and read the uploaded file to import it into MongoDB collection?

What is the efficient way to do this?

Comment: There is no built-in functionality to import CSV files to mongodb. The mongoimport utility reads csv line by line and insert documents to the db. You can do the same. There is nothing specific to koa.